# Moving files without breaking links in AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a website hosted which uses s3 bucket for storing different files (say policy repo). we want to reorganize the files in a proper folder under S3 bucket without breaking the link to these objects in our website. Is there a way to achieve this in S3?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Cloudfront distribution in-front of your s3 bucket and use [AWS Lambda Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) to re-write the URLs mapping to the new moved folder paths without breaking the old URLs.

Answer (score 0):

From [Configuring a Webpage Redirect - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html):

> If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured for website hosting, you can redirect requests for an object to another object in the same bucket or to an external URL.
>
> You set the redirect by adding the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` property to the object metadata. The website then interprets the object as 301 redirect. To redirect a request to another object, you set the redirect location to the key of the target object.

Comment: S3 is not configured for website hosting. So this won't work.

Comment: In that case, you cannot redirect the existing URLs.